# Binding functions in Javascript that operate in the global context

Tags: javascript, binding, bind

I've been driving myself a bit mad trying to figure out how to make this code work. My goal is to produce the output `larry eats pie, larry eats candy, larry eats cake` by binding the function `eats` within the `alice` object to the `larry` object. My hope with the code below was that binding the `alice.eats` function to the larry object would use `larry` as `this.name`, and subsequently applying that function using an array of `larryFoods`, I would hope that it would produce `larry eats + [food]` for each argument.

```
//-----------------Does not work--------------//
var alice = {
      name: "alice",
      speak: function(){
      console.log("Hi, I'm " + this.name);
      },
      eats : function(){
        var theArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        theArgs.forEach(function(arg){
          console.log(this.name + " eats " + arg);
        });
      }
};
var larry = {
    name: "larry"
};
var larrySpeak = alice.speak.bind(larry);
larrySpeak();
var larryFoods = [" pie", " candy", " and cake"];
var larryEats = alice.eats.bind(larry);
larryEats.apply(larryFoods);
```

I am assuming that the forEach function will operate in the global context, which is why I was hoping `bind` would solve the problem. Any insight would be most welcome.

Comment: Note that the `forEach` callback has a new `this`, so you lost the context there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not scoped to the "person" inside of your `forEach` in the `eats` function. Or visually:

```
theArgs.forEach(function(arg){
    // "this".name is trying to resolve name according to the scope of the forEach
    console.log(this.name + " eats " + arg);
});
```

You can fix this like this inside of the `eats` function:

```
var scope = this;
theArgs.forEach(function(arg){
    console.log(scope.name + " eats " + arg);
});
```

Finally, you will need to fix your use of `apply` at the very last line. `apply` needs a context to bind to. Since you already bound the function to `larry`, you can just pass `null` as the first argument:

This:

```
larryEats.apply(larryFoods);
```

should be:

```
larryEats.apply(null, larryFoods);
```

---

**After fixing those things, here is a working example:**

```js
var alice = {
  name: "alice",
  speak: function() {
    console.log("Hi, I'm " + this.name);
  },
  eats: function() {
    var theArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var scope = this;
    theArgs.forEach(function(arg) {
      console.log(scope.name + " eats " + arg);
    });
  }
};
var larry = {
  name: "larry"
};
var larrySpeak = alice.speak.bind(larry);
larrySpeak();
var larryFoods = ["pie", "candy", "and cake"];
var larryEats = alice.eats.bind(larry);
larryEats.apply(null, larryFoods);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
var alice = {
      name: "alice",
      speak: function(){
      console.log("Hi, I'm " + this.name);
      },
      eats : function(){
        var theArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        let that = this;
        theArgs.forEach(function(arg){
          console.log(that.name + " eats " + arg);
        });
      }
};
var larry = {
    name: "larry"
};
var larrySpeak = alice.speak.bind(larry);
larrySpeak();
var larryFoods = [" pie", " candy", " and cake"];
var larryEats = alice.eats;
larryEats.apply(larry, larryFoods);
```